# Differences between "compel" and "impel" in context

Tags: word-choice

Would you please help me understand what are the possible differences between these sentences in terms of meaning and connotation?

> She felt **compelled** to resign because of the scandal.
>
> She felt **impelled** to resign because of the scandal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person who is **impelled** has been persuaded to do something (perhaps based on moral grounds) and does so at least partially of his or her own volition.

**Compel** implies that the person being **compelled** has no choice in the matter and is being coerced. For the person being compelled, the coercion is so strong that choice and morality don’t enter into it.

**Impel** has a sense of motion/pushing, while **Compel** is more of an obligation.

> She felt **compelled** to resign because of the scandal.

This means **she felt forced to resign because of the scandal.**

> She felt **impelled** to resign because of the scandal.

This means **she felt the urge to resign because of the scandal**

Answer (score 3):

The two sentences are very similar.  Both sentences convey the idea that the woman felt a moral or ethical obligation to resign.

The word **compelled** carries a stronger connotation of outside forces pressuring the woman to resign. Perhaps she was the head of a corporation that went through a major scandal and other executives put pressure on her to leave.

**Impelled** implies that her desire to resign was more internally motivated.